# Airflow- Using TriggerDAGRunOperator to trigger DAG of different schedule

Tags: python, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I'm new to Airflow. I need to come up with a clean easy solution for DAG dependencies with different schedules.

I have DAG 1 running Daily and DAG 2 - Weekly.
How do I use TriggerDAGRunOperator to trigger weekly DAG from Daily one?

**DAG 1:**

```
with DAG('DAG 1',
     schedule_interval='0 10 * * *'
     ) as dag:

TASK1 = BashOperator(task_id='TASK1',
                bash_command='sample')
TRG_TASK=TriggerDAGRunOperator(task_id='TRG_TASK',trigger_dag_id='DAG 2')

TASK1 >> TRG_TASK
```

**DAG 2:**

```
with DAG('DAG 2',
     schedule_interval='15 10 * * 5'
     ) as dag:

TASK1 = BashOperator(task_id='TASK1',
                bash_command='sample')
```

I know I can use ExternalTaskSensor Operator and mention timedelta, but it would become messy in long run.

Is there any easy/clean option with TriggerDAGRunOperator to check everyday if DAG 2 is indeed scheduled to run for that day then only trigger it else skip it on other days?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `DAG2` always going to be triggered by `DAG1` and you only want `DAG2` to run weekly or are you expecting `DAG2` will be executed weekly via the cron schedule you listed *or* triggered by `DAG1`?

If the expectation is `DAG2` only gets triggered by `DAG1` but you only want `DAG2` to execute weekly, you can use the [`ShortCircuitOperator`](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/apache-airflow/modules/shortcircuitoperator) in either `DAG1` or `DAG2` and update the `schedule_interval` of `DAG2` to `None` (which means the DAG will only ever be triggered -- either manually or programmatically).

- Option 1: In `DAG1`, add a `ShortCircuitOperator` task prior to executing the `TriggerDagRunOperator` which checks to see if the current day is the desired day of the week.  If it is, then continue on with triggering `DAG2`.
- Option 2: In `DAG2`, add the `ShortCircuitOperator` at the beginning of the workflow that performs the same day of week check.  Again, if the desired day of week then continue on with the rest of the DAG.

Comment: Thanks...this looks good! Also I wanted DAG 2 to trigger weekly at a particular time too. But for that I might have to use TimeSensor. One drawback i see is that if I want DAG 2 to run at say 11 am and DAG 1 got some how delayed and triggered DAG 2 at 11.30 AM, then the Timesenor task will fail but I want DAG 2 to executing tasks even if time is delayed but not by a large margin